# Does Ubuntu work with Coreboot?

Tags: grub2, system-installation, coreboot

Rather, when installed, would the grub be configured properly, or will Ubiquity be confused because it does not find the BIOS?

Comment: Hardware support changes quickly, if anyone comes here to check, see this link to `Linux Hardware` database built by `hw-probe` developer  filtered `coreboot` I saw some Ubuntu machine, mainly Chromebox & Purism HW. https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?view=search&vendor=coreboot#list

Answer (score 2):

I would think that all operating systems and most bootloaders would work with bios, but the question is that would your hardware work with coreboot, that, I do not know. 
It goes like this

OS ->Bootloader ->Bios ->hardware

so I think the OS just needs the BIOS to boot up the bootloader, so the OS itself could load. So the OS is bios-agnostic.

Comment: Yes and no. In most cases the OS checks the BIOS information such as how much memory is available and at what addresses. Then it ignores the BIOS after that. This means most OSes will know how to communicate with the BIOS to learn more about the basic hardware (memory, CPU, disk.)